# GCP "gateway_ip and peer_ip may not be identical" but I can't select the peer IP -- it's always paired & identical to the gateway one

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn, google-vpc, google-cloud-vpn

I've been trying to create a VPN tunnel to connect to the memorystore instance of redis inside GCP from my local machine.

Upon getting to the stage where a VPN tunnel is created -- I can't proceed due to the error in the title.

The issue is I can't make the two ip addresses mentioned different due to them being paired with each other in GCP's interface.

Config:

[image]

Error received:

```
Operation type [insert] failed with message "Failed validation of tunnel riu-development-vpn-tunnel: * gateway_ip and peer_ip may not be identical"
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a VPN tunnel from your local machine or local network to Google Cloud VPN? You must have a supported VPN hardware device installed and configured. What is installed in your local network? Suggestion: for a development machine, set up an SSH tunnel through a VM in the same region as Memorystore.

Comment: I also tried to create one also i am stuck at this part. for the sake of resolving this issue I found this documentation and trying to create again if this works. https://campus.barracuda.com/product/cloudgenfirewall/doc/79462890/how-to-configure-bgp-over-ikev2-ipsec-site-to-site-vpn-to-a-google-cloud-vpn-gateway/